# How safe is totally ordered multicasting using logical clocks?

Tags: distributed-system

I'm new to distributed systems and I'm trying to get my concepts cleared. Not all multicast messages may be received by all processes so by safety, I meant that if two processes P and Q both deliver any two messages M1 and M2, they will do so in the same order.

Comment: By logical clocks do you mean vector clocks?

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Let me explain.

> *This answer makes no assumptions on what you mean by logical clock; ignoring the phrase completely. I'll update the answer when that is clarified. The answer changes if logical clock means **vector clock**, for example.*

In the *Message Passing Model* the network as an **unordered set** of messages. Messages are *sent* by adding to the unordered set, messages are *received* by choosing a random message from the set.

In my experience, this model fits the real world very well, especially as higher throughputs are achieved.

For your example, if P and Q add messages to the network, there is no guarantee that they are delivered in any particular order.